# Rectangular CALayer mask with multiple alpha values

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, mask

I am trying to give the illusion of a navigation bar by masking the top part of a `UITableView`. The top part should have 50% opacity while the rest of the view should have 100% opacity.

This is quite easy to do with a `CAGradientLayer`, like so:

```
- (void)addTopOpacityMask
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.tableView.frame;

    id transparent = (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    id opaque = (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    gradientLayer.colors = @[transparent, opaque, opaque];
    gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.1, @0.11, @1];
    self.tableView.superview.layer.mask = gradientLayer;
}
```

But from what I can tell, every value in the `locations` property needs to be unique, so there will always be a small gradient (which I do not want). Setting locations to

```
@[@0.1, 0.10001, @1];
```

Seems like a very unsexy solution, given that you would also need to translate the height of said mask into locations.

I thought about using CAShapeLayer and simply create the top part as a mask, see code below, but this obviously cuts out the rest of the table view since the mask only covers the top part.

```
- (void)addTopOpacityMask
{
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.opacity = 0.5;
    CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), 76);

    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);
    shapeLayer.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);

    self.tableView.superview.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
}
```

What am I missing?

The reason I want to mask it instead of just adding a 50% transparent view on top of the table view is simple. The table view has a transparent background as well, and I only want the navigation bar to stick out when the user start scrolling beneath it (similar to how the yahoo weather app works/used to work).

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this is what it would look like by default (notice that you cannot see the navbar):

[image]

And this is what it would look like when you start scrolling downwards in the table view (the table view's alpha gets cut off, but we do not change the background color of the view, which is translucent):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit Again: OK... one more try - this might work for you. Played around with it a bit more... It seems to get the effect you want the translucent part of the mask needs a really really low opacity value. Anyway, this code:

```
- (void)addTopOpacityMask {

    CGRect rect = _tableView.frame;
    CGRect r = rect;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // fill a "top rect" with black at 5% opacity
    r.size.height = 76;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.05].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    // fill the rest of the layer with black at 100% opacity
    r.origin.y = 76;
    r.size.height = rect.size.height;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    // grab a UIImage from the context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // create a Layer
    CALayer *theLayer = [CALayer layer];

    // set the Layer content to the just-created image
    theLayer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)(image.CGImage);

    theLayer.frame = rect;

    // mask the view holding the tableview
    _tableView.superview.layer.mask = theLayer;

}
```

gives me this result:

[image]

and

[image]

---

<s>Edit: Not sure I'm seeing what you're seeing... however, have you tried it like this?</s>

```
- (void)addTopOpacityMask
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.tableView.frame;

    id transparent = (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    id opaque = (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    // use 4 color slots
    gradientLayer.colors = @[transparent, transparent, opaque, opaque];

    // and 4 color locations (I don't get an error when using 2 of the same values)
    gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.1, @0.11, @0.11, @1];

    self.tableView.superview.layer.mask = gradientLayer;
}
```

---

You *can* simply create a `CALayer` and give it a translucent background color... Something like this:

```
CALayer *theLayer = [CALayer alloc];
CGRect r = tableView.bounds;
r.size.height = 76.0;
theLayer.frame = r;
theLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
[tableView.superview.layer addSublayer:theLayer];
```

Comment: Doing this would result in changing the appearance of the top part. I basically have a 76 point top inset on the table view, and before you start scrolling, I want the fake navigation bar to not be visible. Only when there are cells underneath it, you would notice that there is something sitting above the tableview. Just like this, but without the gradient transition and with 50% opacity instead of 0%: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559596/clear-color-background-nav-bar-but-still-float-above-all-the-contents

Comment: hmmm.... you initially said "quite easy to do with a CAGradientLayer" except you were still seeing a small gradient appearance... Can you show the code that gets you that far?

Comment: Using the same location twice will not raise an error, but it does result in a gradient. Try it out, you end up with a gradient of a couple of pixels instead of a hard transition. Apple says "The values must be monotonically increasing".

Comment: OK - guess I'm still confused on your layout... Do you *have* a Navigation Bar at the top? With *Activity* as the title, but with the navbar background set to 100% transparent? And so you want your tableview to extend up -and-under the navbar, but get translucent at that point?

Comment: There is no navigation bar there. Like stated in the initial question, I am only using a mask to achieve the looks of one. The only views are a table view and a label.

Comment: One more try - generate a partial-transparent / translucent image to use as the layer mask. (see another edit in my answer)

Comment: @DanielLarsson - just curious... did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: This is a great idea, thanks. Will try it out later today. Only problem could be that my background view is a camera, so it is always changing. I might be able to do some workaround for that though.